# DiscordJS music bot disconnects immediately after starting to play the song

Tags: javascript, discord.js, ytdl

I try to play a Youtube URL but when it starts playing it stops after 1 second. mp3 files are working fine, it just doesn't work when I try to play Youtube URLs.

Here is my Code:

```js
case 'play':
  {
    const Channel = ['903334978199388271'];

    for (const channelId of Channel) {
      joinChannel(channelId);
    }

    function joinChannel(channelId) {
      Client.channels
        .fetch(channelId)
        .then((channel) => {
          const VoiceConnection = joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: channel.id,
            guildId: channel.guild.id,
            adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
          });

          const player = createAudioPlayer();
          VoiceConnection.subscribe(player);
          player.play(
            createAudioResource(
              ytdl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPPsOmQh76A'),
            ),
          );
        })
        .catch(console.error);
    }
  }
  break;
```

Comment: Any errors from the console? Anything that the bot emits?

Comment: No I don't have any errors

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before, the problem is `ytdl-core`, so you can use `ytdl-core-discord` instead. Here is an example:

```
const { Client, Intents, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core-discord')

const {
    joinVoiceChannel,
    createAudioPlayer,
    createAudioResource,
    StreamType
} = require('@discordjs/voice')

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES /// <= Don't miss this :)
    ]
});

var prefix = '!'

client.on('ready', async () => {
    console.log('Client is Ready...');
});

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {

    if (message.content.trim().toLocaleLowerCase() === prefix + 'play') {

        const channel = client.channels.cache.get('Channel ID Here')

        const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: channel.id,
            guildId: channel.guildId,
            adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
        });

        const player = createAudioPlayer();
        const resource = createAudioResource(await ytdl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPPsOmQh76A'), { inputType: StreamType.Opus });

        player.play(resource);

        connection.subscribe(player);
    }
});


client.login('Bot Token Here!');
```